# What is better/faster or safer .Include() or Get Entity separately?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity Project and then I have an entity Ticket that has a `projectId`. Before for Details page, I find the project

```
public async Task<Project> FindByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _db.Projects
                .Include(p => p.ApplicationUsers)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
        }
```

and then I find the tickets by `projectId`

```
public async Task<ICollection<Ticket>> GetAllTicketsForProject(int projectId)
        {
            return await _db.Tickets
                .Where(t => t.ProjectId == projectId)
                .Include(t => t.AssignedUser)
                .Include(t=>t.Project)
                .OrderBy(t=> t.DateCreated)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

When deleting the ticket I found out about cascade deletion and that I can just make

```
public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
```

and now I can just Include all the comments in the query. That was something new to me.
Now I would like to know what is the better practice? To use Include on queries or Get the entities separately?

Comment: A database is build for querying data. So I'd say, use that power. Therefor, IMHO, I would suggest to include related tables in a query to get the data that you need. This is simple, readable and most likely faster.

Comment: It's better and faster to do it with the include because like this the query will be performed with Joins (INNER JOINS, LEFT JOINS...), it's just one query, one execution plan.

If you look for it separately the app will perform differents querys.

Comment: It depends. If there would be a relatively big number comments then fetching just to delete would be not a very good idea. Note that out of the box EF is not very suitable to perfrom batch/bulk operations, so usually you will need to either write some custom logic or use one of [existing tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you would be better off to include your `Tickets` entity in your `Projects` query. You are putting more work on the database, sure, but thats what the power of the DB and `JOIN`s are there for.

As it stands, you are making two round trips to the database, and, you will most likely see a performance increase by including the child entity in the query.

Where you would *really* have trouble with not using an `.Include()` properly is fetching a collection of entities, and then looping through those entities and attempting to access a navigation property off that entity that hasn't been fetched; [the infamous n+1 problem](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/common-entity-framework-problems-n-1/).

Comment: Thank you. I like using include better as well. Cleaner and easier to use.